# Javascript Menu toggle with Media Queries

Tags: javascript

How do I remove an event listener and class from an element in relation to a media query. I have been fiddling around with this, but nothing seems to work. It works fine on moblie, but when I re-size the screen to become larger the 'menu-show' class is still there.

How would I use this with `removeEventListener` , it did not seem to work for me.

```
function showMobileOptions(x) {
  if (x.matches) { 
      filters.forEach(filter => filter.addEventListener('click', function(){
        filter.querySelector('.menu-list').classList.toggle("menu-show");
        filter.querySelector('.menu-list').classList.toggle("toggle-close");
      }))
    } else {
      //remove event listener + '.menu-show' from all items
     filters.forEach(filter, function(){
      filter.querySelector('.menu-list').classList.remove("menu-show");
      filter.querySelector('.menu-list').classList.remove("toggle-close");
  });
  }
}

const x = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 768px)")
showMobileOptions(x)
x.addListener(showMobileOptions)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use it like this

```
filter.removeEventListener('click');
```

Best practice is to create a function for what you do when click fire, and then use the remove

```
filter.removeEventListener('click',myClickFunction);
```

Comment: Both type and listener function are required parameters.

Comment: great thanks vincent + johan, I tried this and it worked